# Remove data from Firebase using Sketchware

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have just created a small app in Sketchware. I connected with Firebase and I know how to push data to firebase. The problem is How to remove them. I can't find how to read pushkey node.

More on the image[image]

Any ideas?
Regards
Jack

Comment: Hey Jack. I've never used Sketchware, but it seems that there is a `delete_key` operation: https://docs.sketchware.io/docs/component-firebase-database.html#delete-key

Comment: Hi Thank you. I know this but how to get this key?

Comment: Normally you'd get it from the `Map` that you read from the database. Each element in the map consists of a `key` (which identifies the element) and a `value` (which you display).

Comment: Hi Frank and this is my question how to get it:)

Comment: This video seems to shows how to do this using an `onChildAdded` listener: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58I0_sp9uBg (specifically [here](https://youtu.be/58I0_sp9uBg?t=1m48s)).

Comment: I downloaded Sketchware and am trying to reproduce. But I somehow don't see a component with the `get children to` that you have. Where can I find it?

Comment: I think I just found that one. While searching further, I came across this blog post that seems to do what you want: http://www.sketchwarehelp.com/2018/01/how-to-delete-data-from-firebase.html

Answer (score 0):

The block "get value at" without position seems to missing